# getActivity null in fragment when app resumes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

So if the user is on my app and they click home and go to several other apps and then come back, then the activity will be recreated and `getActivity` will be null when I call on it in my fragment.

A solution I found was to create a static variable and store `getActivity` in the `onCreateView`.

I feel like this isn't a good solution. Is there any other way that I can go about this?

I tried using a non static variable and storing it in OncreateView and onAttach, but getActivity will be null.

Here is the error I will get when I use `getActivity` if I don't save it as a static variable. I use it in my `AsyncTask` for ProcessDialog in my Fragment.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

Thanks.

Comment: What override method are you calling  when you have getActivity() as null?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that `onAttach(Activity activity)` also has null, then I suspect you have multiple instance of same fragment at the same time. Print the fragment instance in onResume and check the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing the method **onActivityCreated**? You should use getActivity inside this method.

Another workaround would be use onAttach to keep your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
 super.onAttach(activity);
 mActivity = activity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have already tried this. It will only work if the variable is static. I feel like using a static variable is wrong. But I will do this until i find or figure something else out.